# Xpath | Change @codeListValue

Tags: xml, xpath, metadata, batch-processing, geonetwork

I have the following XML snippet, referring to a metadata published in my GeoNetwork:

```
<mri:spatialRepresentationType>
  <mcc:MD_SpatialRepresentationTypeCode codeList="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19115/resources/Codelists/cat/codelists.xml#MD_SpatialRepresentationTypeCode" codeListValue="grid"/>
</mri:spatialRepresentationType>
```

I would like to change the @codeListValue="grid" to "Matricial" using the advanced (XPath) mode of GeoNetwork (3.10.2), but I believe that I not been able to create the appropriate XPath.

[image: test in xpath mode of geonetwork]

Comment: You are close, just add `/@codeListValue` to your XPath

Comment: like this: //mri:spatialRepresentationType/mcc:MD_SpatialRepresentationTypeCode/@codeListValue = 'grid' ?? I tried, but geonetwork does not make any change in xmls